# Android nougat (Android 7) app update issue clear all old data when app existing app

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

When I updated my existing app by new version of my app in android 7 my app old store data has been cleared but in old version app working nice. Please solve my issue if any one have any suggestion my tell me.

Comment: phone settings has a value that affects the app data on an install .   You can wipe old app data with each install or leave old data with install/upgrade. so try changing that value in settings

Comment: Could you explain more ? and which value need to change inside settings. And can we modify value programmatically?

Comment: Backup&reset/automatic restore .... turn it off and you get a wipe along with each install  dont recall exactly what data this affects. I do remember needing to test 'fresh' install where some condition failed until i turned this off.